# Existe alguma forma de generalizar as importações de bibliotecas em Java?

Tags: java, packages

Eu criei dentro de um mesmo pacote chamado `Banco`, duas classes em Java: `ContaSalario` e `ContaPoupanca`. Quando vou importar essas duas classe na minha classe principal, eu faço:

```
import Banco.ContaSalario;    
import Banco.ContaPoupanca;
```

Existe alguma forma de importar todas as classes de um mesmo pacote com uma única chamada? Por exemplo:

```
import Banco.all;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É possível, basta fazer:

```
import Banco.*
```

Que importará todas as classe do pacote `Banco`.

Perceba entretanto que de acordo com o JavaBeans, pacotes devem ter a primeira letra minuscula, que é justamente para diferenciar das classes. Então o mais apropriado seria mudar seu pacote de `Banco` para `banco`. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
import banco.*
```

Answer (score 6):

Importe assim:

> import Banco.*

É só colocar .* depois do ultimo pacote que você deseja importar

Comment: Vale notar duas coisas aqui: essa é a primeira vez que eu vejo duas respostas sendo postadas no mesmo exato segundo :) A outra coisa a se notar é que não tem um pacote `Conta` dentro do pacote `Banco` :(

Comment: não tem problema, é só colocar o "." + * depois do ultimo pacote que vc deseja importar

Answer (score 5):

Sim, dá fazendo isto:

```
import Banco.*
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Import.java).

Esta forma importa todas as classes existentes no mesmo pacote.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).