# Importar várias classes de um mesmo pacote

Tags: java, memória, importação, packages

Gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença significativa em fazer

```
import java.util.*
```

em vez de

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Minha dúvida é se eu estou "sobrecarregando" o classloader se eu usar o wildcard Em vez de uma lista com as classes específicas. Isto é, o *classloader* vai carregar todas as classes do pacote `java.util` na JVM mesmo se eu não for usá-las? Vai ter influência na performance da memória se eu abusar do uso de *wildcards*? Por fim, qual é a boa prática?

[Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88316/existe-alguma-forma-de-generalizar-as-importa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-bibliotecas-em-java)

Comment: A segunda opção, o correto é você importar a classe que vai usar diretamente, a não ser que vá usar todas as classes de um pacote muito extenso, ai a chamada com o coringa compensa mais, mas não consigo imaginar um cenário onde isso irá ocorrer.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 6):

Não, a não ser que importe tudo mesmo, até alguma coisa que pode não querer que importe. Nada impede que tenha conflitos de nomes nas classes que forem importadas e você pode nem perceber até usar. Usando o nome explicitamente você seleciona melhor o que será importado.

O uso do `*` garante que tudo será importado, até mesmo o que ainda não existe. Se criar uma nova classe no futuro dentro do `util` com o asterisco ela será importada, se fizer individualmente é claro que não será importada se você não mudar seu código. O que não deve ser importante porque certamente seu código não faz uso dele.

Claro que ele importa tudo o que está naquele nível de pacote, ele não o faz recursivamente.

Não há perda de performance na carga do aplicativo. Pelo menos não no código. Pode haver um custo adicional virtualmente imperceptível na compilação porque pode ter mais lugares para ele procurar por símbolos usados no seu código. Mas não será mais que o tempo decorrido se tivesse colocado todos pacotes um por um na mão. A diferença seria só pela quantidade.

A diferença é a intenção mesmo. Você quer importar tudo mesmo, ou uma lista de pacotes, mesmo que sejam, por acaso, todos?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os pacotes mais internos acho que não são importados, houve vários casos onde fiz uso de classes em subpacotes de determinado pacote com o coringa `*` e o java obrigou a importar o subpacote todo ou a classe dentro desse subpacote.

Comment: @diegofm ah sim, tem que fazer por nível. O `*` não é `*.*.*.*` :)

Answer (score 6):

Em relação a memória não há diferença, a instrução `import` serve apenas para dizer onde se encontram as classes utilizadas.

Porém há uma vantagem em usar importando diretamente a classe. Caso existam classes com o mesmo nome em dois pacotes ocorrerá um conflito em relação a qual classe está sendo referenciada.

Por exemplo, utilizando os pacotes `javax.swing.text` e `org.w3c.dom`, considerando que os dois tem a classe `Element`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

...

Element elemento;
```

Neste caso o `Element` utilizado é de qual pacote?

Já no seguinte exemplo:

```
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

...

Element elemento;
```

Sabemos assim que o `Element` utilizado é do pacote `org.w3c.dom`. Então na realidade existe uma vantagem em explicitar as classes importadas no âmbito de facilitar a leitura e entendimento do código. Não que importar com `*` seja ruim ou errado, apenas facilita manutenções futuras.

Importar todas as classes de um pacote com `*` é justificado apenas pela facilidade de não precisar alterar as importações manualmente para cada nova classe utilizada. Para facilitar neste aspecto e evitar que seja necessário ter conhecimento do caminho exato para o pacote que será utilizado, as principais `IDEs` de desenvolvimento `Java` possuem atalhos para otimizar as importações, removendo as que não estão sendo utilizadas e apresentando opções de pacotes para as que não estão declaradas. Algumas estão listadas abaixo (Na configuração padrão):

- *Netbeans:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- *Eclipse:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- *IntelliJ:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

[image: Atalho - Netbeans]

---

**Referências de respostas para perguntas semelhantes no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):**

- [Any difference between class imports and package imports in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553924/3388148)
- [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147461/3388148)